# What is the "special service" at the Blooming Rose?

Tags: dragon-age-2

There are rumors that the mistress of the Blooming Rose (in Hightown of Kirkwall) will provide a "special service" for regular customers.  Is this a quest line?  Am I missing out on story content or is it just flavor text from a loading screen?

*I haven't bothered to spend time in there unless there's a mission forcing me in the door (my male Hawke is smitten with Isabella and my FemHawke thinks the whole place is stupid).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to being a bar and an inn, the Blooming Rose happens to be a brothel: if you choose the correct dialog options when talking to the Mistress, you can choose amongst several of her... companions to spend some time with.

Furthermore, if you choose to get the "Royal Treatment",

> one possible companion you'll be treated to is a male elf in drag.

Beyond that, you'll sometimes get an option to ask for something exotic or special:

> This option is a switcheroo: for example, as a female Hawke, you can ask for something "for girls who have been bad." You'll be treated to a lecture by a Chantry priest.

Whatever you choose, it doesn't affect any quests: it's just there for flavor.

Comment: Okay, those are funny.  I'm glad to know that they're in there and I'm also glad that I didn't bother with them in game....  ;-)